# Angular2 (Typescript) - Dynamically binded html doesnt apply script formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, formatting, innerhtml

This script is in my index.html's :

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

If I write a line of html **statically** in the component.html, it correctly applies the formatting from a script. (1) in image.

However, once I let angular bind it, (2) and (3) in image, the script in the  is not applied and the result is that the html is rendered as plain html. I tried binding it through [innerHTML] and setting an #ID

[image: Here is the three methods that I have tried. Only static HTML applies correct format]

How can I get the nice formatting in (1) with a dynamic string?

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Request } from "./Request";

@Component({
  selector: 'html-component',
  templateUrl: './html.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./html.component.css'],
  providers: [Request]
})
export class HtmlComponent implements OnInit {  
  questionString = '';
  answerString = '';
  currentQuestion;
  type;
  @ViewChild('questionId') questionId: ElementRef;
```

I set the value of the inner html here:

```
this.request.postHtml("openLink",result)
      .then(response => {   
          this.questionId.nativeElement.innerHTML =
              response._body.replace(/{/g, '{{\'{\'}}');

      console.log(this.questionId.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      this.questionString = response._body.replace(/{/g, '{{\'{\'}}');
```

I dont have a real template. Its mainly in one big HTML file.

HTML (again):
[image]

HTML Output:
[image]

And I have tried placing the  before the [innerHTML] binding. It doesnt change anything since I've already included the  in the index.html (parent of this html page)

Comment: Show enough of your component and template that we have a better understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: @BeetleJuice thanks. Updated it with my component.ts. Not much to show in my template other than whats already shown

Comment: You said it works with static HTML? How could it? I notice that you are calling `MathJax.Hub.Config()` before you even load the MathJax library. Also, if you `console.log()` the result of `response._body.replace(...)` then manually copy and statically include that in the template, does it work? (just making sure that what you generate dynamically is the correct string)

Comment: @beetlejuice I just tried it again, and it works. IDK how to add a img in this comment, so I'll just update the OP again. Yes, that is exactly what I did. I copied the console.log into the .html page again and indeed it appears nicely

Comment: (1) Once your component is built, can `questionString` change dynamically or will it keep its initially set value? (2) where exactly are you calling `this.request.postHtml().then...`? Is that in a function or event handler?

Comment: @BeetleJuice, yes questionString changes after it is built. I can click on different questions to get different questionString's and the page will update nicely. The value gets updated inside this.request.postHtml which returns a json object response. I set the questionString to the body of the response object.

Comment: Ok I get the answer to my #1, but not #2. Where are you calling `this.request()` from? You put the call in your question, but there is no way for me to understand the context: is that code block physically located within a greater function?

Comment: @BeetleJuice it's located in a helper component that sends requests to my http server  >>>>> postHtml(url, data): Promise<any>
 {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/' + url, data).map(response => {
   return response || {success: false, message: "No response from server"};
  }).catch((error: Response | any) => {
   return Observable.throw(error.json());
  }).toPromise();
 }'

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic problem is that MathJax processes the page before Angular can build the template and databind properties. You need to process the math *after* Angular has done its job. Basically you need to make use of `MathJax.Hub` to imperatively ask MathJax to process and render the math string when you need it (meaning after Angular is done putting it on the page).

I would make use of your `@ViewChild() questionId` like so:

```
this.request.postHtml().then(response => {

   // capture the element that will hold the math
   let div = this.questionId.nativeElement;

   //populate the div with math input string. Try innerText before using innerHTML
   div.innerText = ...;

   //process the div's contents and render the math
   MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, div]);
})
```

More details [available here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html).  By the way you should [stop using cdn.mathjax.org](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can't wait to get home and try it!

Comment: Cool let me know how it goes. I wrote another answer that takes a different approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I'm seeing the notifications but I'm not home yet. Will definitely update! I really appreciate the help, sir.

Comment: I have tried the implementing this after installing mathjax in my node modules and importing it correctly. But now get an error in the chrome console upon  postHtml  saying Cannot read property 'Hub' of undefined

Comment: In fact, I just tested it again to console.log(Hub.version) and its saying: 'Cannot read property 'version' of undefined'. Basically I'm not importing MathJax properly still or not accessing the MathJax variable correctly??

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is what I wrote in my other answer (MathJax is acting *before* Angular finishes rendering the template, so to fix you need to wait for your component to load before rendering math).

This answer is a totally different approach from my other answer. You could use a Directive to handle the job. Attach it to any element and use data-binding to display math within that element. For example, if the directive has selector `[mathText]`, you would simply bind it to the component property that holds the raw string:

```
<div [mathText]="questionString"></div>
```

In the directive, MathJax would parse the text and render the equations in the `<div>`.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector : '[mathText]',
})
export class MathTextDirective implements OnChanges {
    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.hostEl = elementRef.nativeElement; //capture the HTML element host
    }

    //Used to bind data: eg: <div [mathText]="raw string">
    @Input('mathText') inputString:string;
    // host element
    private hostEl:HTMLElement;

    //have MathJax parse the host element and render the math
    render(){MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, this.hostEl])}

    // called when the inputString changes.
    ngOnChanges(){
        //make the input string into the innerText of the host element
        this.hostEl.innerText = this.inputString;
        this.render();
    }
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://embed.plnkr.co/uMQTaMiI2TzfK71x9YOo/)

Comment: I know this is going to sound dumb but Im struggling with a basic thing. I tried both approaches and searching the web, but I stuck with include MathJax into my  component.ts file so I can actually use MathJax.* functions. I have npm install mathjax and it exists in my app's root folder on the same level as src. How can I include this? Should it be installed in node_modules? https://ibb.co/bGmdNk

Comment: I tried the method on the pluncker. I put the mathtext.directive.ts on the level of my component.ts and updated my app.module.ts to 'import { MathTextDirective } from './html/mathtext.directive' and added the declaration. However, Im getting an ierror in mathtext.directrive.ts: 'Cannot find name 'MathJax'. Do I need some kind of additional import or installation of MathJAx?

Comment: @AllenH. In my live demo there is a script tag that fetches MathJax from cdnjs.cloudflare.com.  Look at my [index.html](https://embed.plnkr.co/uMQTaMiI2TzfK71x9YOo/). So I don't need a component-specific include. That's why the demo works

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help once again. I tried doing that last night, and just tried the method on your plunker again with a fresh mind this morning. I put the mathtext.directive.ts in my \app\ folder, on the same level as app.module.ts. Inside my appmodule, I import mathtextdirective successfully and declare it successfully inside @NgModules. However, the compiler complains that inside the copied mathtext.directive.ts I cant find name 'MathJax'

Comment: @AllenH. Yes you can expect that to happen since the compiler doesn't know anything about MathJax. It can't see what an external script will load at run time. If you want to get rid of this error, you'll need to either declare an object in your component `MathJax:any={}` or research how to load and import the MathJax library into TypeScript (in that case you won't need to load it at run time using script tags anymore)

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. I added a MathJax: Any = {} in the mathjax.directive.ts file and now the compiler doesnt complain about missing MathJax, but rather no Hub method exists on {}. It is still compiling everything inside the ngOnChanges() function before runtime. How can I get around this?

Comment: change `MathJax:any={}` to `MathJax:any`, so it's not set to anything the compiler can parse

Comment: I got it to work! Everything you wrote was very helpful and in the end I used parts from the method described here http://ruinshe.moe/2016/05/31/support-mathjax-in-angular2/  I created a new directive and incldued that declaration in my module.ts. Now I am able to format strings!

Comment: Congrats. If my post helped solve your problem then upvote or select it. Thanks for the link. I'll take a look because I'm also interested in using MathJax in an Angular app

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried upvoting all your posts, but it says that it wont show since I'm a newbie here.

Comment: @AllenH. No problem it's a restriction to prevent fraudulent upvotes. I went through the code you linked to. It uses the same solution as I do, though I like how it uses `declare var MathJax` to keep the compiler happy. That's better than what I suggested. One difference though: that other code uses `innerHTML` but I prefer `innerText` because it's more secure (the browser won't try to parse the text, since it won't be considered HTML)